# Caffe Python | Low accuracy of GoogleNet could be caused by bad form of input data?

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I am quite new to Caffe and Deep Learning so please bear with my inexperience and naive questions. 
Now to the point, I want to train GoogleNet using the FER2013 dataset(it consists of faces and it's purpose is to recognise one of the 7 categories the faces fall into). However the data isn't in an image format rather than an array of 48x48=2304 values with each value being between 0 and 255. So in order to create the lmdb files needed to feed the Caffe I wrote the following Python script to transform the arrays into real images.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import csv
import itertools

with open('fer2013.csv', 'rb') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    i=0
    for row in itertools.islice(mycsv, 340):
        data = row[1]
        data = data.split()
        data = map(int, data)
        data = np.array(data)
        im = Image.fromarray(data.reshape((48,48)).astype('uint8')*255)
        directory='imagestotest/'
        path_to_save = directory+"image"+str(i)+".jpg"
        path = "image"+str(i)+".jpg"
        im.save(path_to_save)
        i=i+1
        with open("testset.txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(path+" "+row[0]+"\n")
```

I then prepare my lmdb files with the following command

> GLOG_logtostderr=1 ./deep-learning/caffe/build/tools/convert_imageset --resize_height=256 --resize_width=256 --shuffle /home/panos/Desktop/images/  /home/panos/Desktop/trainingset.txt /home/panos/Desktop/train_lmdb

Finally, I compute the image_mean, I change the train_val.prototxt and set loss1,loss2,loss3 layers to have num_output=7 (as I have 7 classes, 0-6).

I run my model (training size: 5000 and test size: 340) and the accuracy is rather disappointing, being close to 23%(top-1), 88.8%(top-5).

Could this be a hyper parameter configuration problem, or is it that my input files are not created correctly? (as I fear my Python cooking skills)

If it helps, my main hyper parameters are: test_iter: 7,test_interval: 40,base_lr: 0.001,momentum: 0.9,weight_decay: 0.0002.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your are resizing `48 X 48` into `256 X 256`. This might be a problem. Did you use Googlenet pretrained model for weight initialization?

Comment: @Inman How can I do that ? And what does it offer ? Thanks a million for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a pretrained model you will need to download googlenet model first from [here](http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel) . Now you can use this command:

`caffe train —solver solver.prototxt —weights bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel`

One of the main problem with training is weight initialization. Without proper initialization the model might not converge showing poor performance. You can't initialize all weights with the same value. Some other recommendations are weights should be sparse, orthogonal, normalized etc. So it is usually recommended to use weights from a pretrained model. It can be called transfer learning. For details of weight initialization you can see [this by karpathy](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#init). You can also see [What are good initial weights in a neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47590/what-are-good-initial-weights-in-a-neural-network) If you want deeper understanding see the following papers.

[1] Bengio, Yoshua. "Practical recommendations for gradient-based training of deep architectures." Neural Networks: Tricks of the Trade. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2012. 437-478.

[2] LeCun, Y., Bottou, L., Orr, G. B., and Muller, K. (1998a). Efficient backprop. In Neural Networks, Tricks of the Trade.

[3] Glorot, Xavier, and Yoshua Bengio. "Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks." International conference on artificial intelligence and statistics. 2010.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will try it right now. May I bother you with one more question? I can see in the data layer of the Googlenet that the crop_size =224. When I made my lmdb files, I changed the resizing parameters to 48x48 and it didn't accept them as they were smaller than the 224 I just mentioned. So now I changed them to 224 as it wants them to be. Isn't that a bit strange though ? My input is 48x48, why would I have to make it larger ? Should I interfere with the googlenets train_val and change the crop size to 48 ? Or is this going to affect every aspect of the file ? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should try both. It might be interesting to find which one works better.

Comment: Using the pretrained GoogleNet got me from 23% (top1) accuracy, to 24%(top1). Any other ideas on how I could improve it? Just mentioning that the FER2013 dataset is a hard one to achieve high accuracy since the faces are photographed in the wild and not in a studio. However, several papers I've read have achieved over 60% (top1).

Comment: Of course ! Here it is:

net: "models/bvlc_googlenet/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 7
test_interval: 40
test_initialization: false
display: 40
average_loss: 40
base_lr: 0.001
lr_policy: "step"
stepsize: 320000
gamma: 0.96
max_iter: 200
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0002
snapshot: 40000
snapshot_prefix: "models/bvlc_googlenet/bvlc_googlenet"
solver_mode: CPU

Comment: Your test interval seems too small. How many iteration did you try? Can you plot your loss?

Comment: I made it so small so I would not have to wait for too long in order to see some indicating results. Does that affect it's accuracy for any reason ?

Comment: Small max_iter is not a good indicator of what would happen. So I tried fer2013 for 1000 iteration  with all batchsize 16. It already  achieves ~47% accuracy. Here is the link to all of my settings https://pastebin.com/3d7sDGKK . Note: I converted images from gray to rgb.

Comment: Thanks a million. I will try it as soon as I get home ! I'm marking your answer because it solved a lot more questions than I expected.

Comment: @Inman So I tried what u suggested, without using the pretrained weights though, as it gives me an error when I try to use the pretrained weights along with the batch_size=16. And I am still at that annoying 24 %. (the exact error message is: **Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'loss1/classifier'; shape mismatch.  Source param shape is 1 1 1000 1024 (1024000); target param shape is 7 1024 (7168).** ) Any other ideas ?

Comment: Don't set loss num_output to 7. Only thing you need to change in googlenet is image mean? You did set all three channel mean to 125 right? I did set batch size due to my ram limitation.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why I should make my channel means = 125 ? And how are batch size and RAM connected mathematically ? I mean how do I calculate what batch size to use ? Thank you !

Comment: I just tried several batch size until I didn't get out of memory. You can calculate it but that will too broad to discuss here. As for image mean I calculated it for training images. In your question you said you calculated image mean. what was your image mean?

Comment: I calcualted it usiong my train_lmdb data by executing the following script from within my main Caffe folder: 

**TOOLS=build/tools

$TOOLS/compute_image_mean /home/panos/Desktop/train_lmdb \
  /home/panos/Desktop/image_mean.binaryproto

echo "Done.".** By the way, shouldn't I make the output_num = 7? I mean how can it possibly categorize the images if it assumes that there are 1000 classes by default ?

Comment: Inner product layer weights have to be loaded as is. You can't load those weight by changing shape. Although it will predict 1000 class you will train on only 7. So other class predictions after training will be very low. Also you probably should learn about deep learning before doing anything.

Comment: The thing is I am supposed to use these methods and different CNN architectures as black boxes and simply measure the performance of some datasets on them (for my thesis). So I do not want to get lost in the mathematical background of each one. If however you have any suggestions on some studying source which is a bit more applied, I would be grateful. Thanks for all the help so far !

Comment: try http://cs231n.stanford.edu/ . Previous videos of this course are available online. it is a good starting point.